# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint forxml issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query with me:

```
select
(
    select ', '+ a.CustomMessage from t_Activity a where a.ActivityId in 
    (
        select item from function_split(par.Fault,',')
        for xml path('')
    )
)
from t_quoteheader qh inner join
t_HandsetQuote hq on qh.quoteheaderid = hq.quoteheaderid
join t_PhoneAudit pa on hq.QuotePhoneAuditId = pa.PhoneAuditId
join t_PhoneAuditRetail par on hq.HandsetQuoteId = par.HandsetQuoteId
```

And, when I run it, I get this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Note: Reason for getting this error is that my `ActivityId` is of type `BigInt` and `par.Fault` is of `varchar` type.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: show some sample data

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar what sample data?

Comment: @HarshSharma, what is fucntion_split giving back, what is sample value of par.fault, is it comma seperated, why you are doing for xml path?

Comment: @RADAR yes, `par.fault` is containing comma separated value, i am using `xml` because i have to use `Stuff` function later

Comment: "i am using xml because i have to use Stuff function later" - that makes no sense.

Comment: The error is about 99.9% likely because you have some value in your comma delimited list (that is its own nightmare that should be dealt with) that is not able to be converted to an int.

Comment: Are you trying to convert par.Fault into comma separated values in  "function_split" function

Answer (score 0):

the function_split is returning the tokens as varchar, convert them to bigint and compare

remove for xml path('')

```
select cast(item as bigint) from function_split(par.Fault,',')
```